# How to get Pricebook2 Sharing Rules using UserRecordAccess

Tags: apex, visualforce, soql, sharing, pricebook

I have an Apex class `with sharing` where I get a list of every `Pricebook2` available in the database. Considering the fact that we use sharing rules to prevent access to some of them, my SOQL shouldn't return a full list to every users.

Here's my super simple method:

```
public SelectOption[] getPricebookList() {
    Pricebook2[] Records =
    [
        SELECT
            Name
        FROM
            Pricebook2
        WHERE
            IsActive = true
        ORDER BY
            Name ASC
    ];

    SelectOption[] Options = new SelectOption[]{};

    for(Pricebook2 R : Records)
        Options.add(new SelectOption(R.Id, R.Name));

    return Options;
}
```

The data returned by this method is then outputted using a `selectoption` component inside a Visualforce page.

The problem I have is that every price books are displayed to every single users. Also, any user can use the Visualforce module I created to create Quotes and QuoteLineItems with any Pricebook, even if they don't have access to them according to the sharing settings.

How can I prevent this from happening?

**EDIT (@SF_Ninja)**

I tried what you answer, here's my code:

```
// Requesting available price books
Map<ID, Pricebook2> Records = new Map<ID, Pricebook2>([
    SELECT   Name
    FROM     Pricebook2
    WHERE    IsActive = true
    ORDER BY Name ASC
]);

SelectOption[] Options = new SelectOption[]{};

// Requesting price books user access
// NOTE: Workaround since Pricebook2 doesn't enforce Sharing Rules
UserRecordAccess[] UserRecordAccessList =
[
    SELECT  RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, HasDeleteAccess
    FROM    UserRecordAccess
    WHERE   UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND 
            RecordID IN :Records.keySet()
];

System.debug('User ID: ' + UserInfo.getUserId());
System.debug('Pricebook IDs size: ' + Records.keySet().size());

System.debug('IDs to search:');

for(Pricebook2 R : Records.values())
    System.debug('----> ' + R.Name + ' (' + R.Id + ')');

System.debug('Result: ' + UserRecordAccessList); // <-- returning () as admin
```

According to the documentation, I'm requesting the right values, have the right `WHERE` operations (http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_userrecordaccess.htm).

Here's the Developer console output:

[image]

UserID and Pricebook IDs are both returning values, but the last `debug` is returning an empty list. Still trying to figure out whats going on here.

**EDIT (2013-11-14 10:00)**

Here's the final version of the code provided above. The reason why the version above wasn't working is because I passed a `set` instead of a `list` in the `WHERE` condition. Normally, this would be working in a SOQL request, but not in this case. I guess there's an undocumented limitation in `UserRecordAccessList`.

```
// Requesting available price books
Map<ID, Pricebook2> Records = new Map<ID, Pricebook2>([
    SELECT   Name
    FROM     Pricebook2
    WHERE    IsActive = true
    ORDER BY Name ASC
]);

SelectOption[] Options = new SelectOption[]{};

Id[] PBIDs = new Id[]{};

PBIDs.addAll(Records.keySet());

// Requesting price books user access
// NOTE: Workaround since Pricebook2 doesn't enforce Sharing Rules
UserRecordAccess[] UserRecordAccessList =
[
    SELECT  RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, HasDeleteAccess
    FROM    UserRecordAccess
    WHERE   UserId = :UserInfo.getUserId() AND 
            RecordID IN :PBIDs
];

System.debug('User ID: ' + UserInfo.getUserId());
System.debug('Pricebook IDs size: ' + Records.keySet().size());

System.debug('IDs to search:');

for(Pricebook2 R : Records.values())
    System.debug('----> ' + R.Name + ' (' + R.Id + ')');

System.debug('Result: ' + UserRecordAccessList);
```

Hope this might fix others issue.

**EDIT (2013-11-14 10:37)**

The code above is working (we can get `UserRecordAccessList` records), but every permissions are set to `yes`, so it's pointless.

What is left to do?

Hack in Salesforce features to set the Pricebook:

`https://[INSTANCE].salesforce.com/oppitm/choosepricebook.jsp?id=[OPP_ID]&retURL=[RET_URL]`

This might break your flow, but it should be working and support sharing settings.

Comment: This seems very odd.  The query should work.  If I change the RecordID IN : map.keyset() to just RecordId = (any id from the keyset), it works fine.  very odd.  Messing around in my dev org with the query to try to figure it out

Comment: @SF_Ninja When I insert IDs manually (`WHERE RecordID IN ('id', 'id2', 'id3'...)`), it is working and returning the right information. Maybe this special SOQL request is allergic to my `Records.keySet()`. Considering all the limitation mentioned in the documentation, I feel there's some magic done behind the scene. It is written like a regular SOQL request, but probably parsed before executing it. I might have to craft my request dynamically and populate the `WHERE` condition using a loop.

Comment: keyset() returns a set, not a list.  I might try creating a list in this way: list<Id> keySetList = new list<Id>(Records.keyset()).  Then you could use this list for RecordID IN : keySetList.  I havent tried this, but it occured to me that keyset() does return a set, not a list.  This shouldnt be an issue, but it occured to me maybe this is what is causing the iodd behavior

Comment: Yeah, it's returning a set. I dug a bit more online and end up on this message on the forum (http://boards.developerforce.com/t5/Apex-Code-Development/determine-edit-delete-permissions-in-code/m-p/462757/highlight/true#M84708) saying that `Set<ID>` doesn't work, while `List<ID>` does when requesting `UserRecordAccess` object. It's strange, since they normally work in SOQL queries. Like I mentioned, it must be the magic done in the background that doesn't support this. There's not even an error returned!

Comment: API v39 still no change: `SELECT Id, Name, UserRecordAccess.HasReadAccess, UserRecordAccess.HasTransferAccess, UserRecordAccess.MaxAccessLevel FROM Pricebook2` returns all `true` resp MaxAccessLvl: `"Id":"01s0Y000005JVMyQAO","Name":"Not shared with anyone","UserRecordAccess":{"attributes":{"type":"UserRecordAccess"},"HasReadAccess":true,"HasTransferAccess":true,"MaxAccessLevel":"All"}` - taken from a vf page viewed as standard user with none shared pricebooks (dev org, can't test in production).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is a known issue with the pricebook2 object in Salesforce.

> From the Apex Developers guide.

[image]

**See here**

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/apexcode/index_Left.htm#StartTopic=Content/apex_security_sharing_rules.htm?SearchType=Stem

**There is an idea you can vote on to get this feature here**

https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000ZE28AAG

As a workaround you can use the UserRecordAccess object in your Apex to only add the pricebook that the current user has access to, to the list of selectoptions.  This is not ideal, but its a work around.

**Note I did this in a text browser, so it hasnt been tested, but something like this should work for you**

```
public SelectOption[] getPricebookList() {
    Pricebook2[] Records = [SELECT Name FROM Pricebook2 WHERE IsActive = true ORDER BY Name ASC];

    SelectOption[] Options = new SelectOption[]{};

    set<Id> pricebookIDs = new set<Id>();
    for(Pricebook2 R : Records){
        pricebookIDs.add(R.Id);
    }

    List<UserRecordAccess> listUserRecordAccess = [SELECT RecordId, HasReadAccess, HasEditAccess, 
       HasDeleteAccess FROM UserRecordAccess WHERE UserId=:UserInfo.getUserId() AND RecordId IN: pricebookIDs];

    map<Id,boolean> accessMap = new map<Id,boolean>();

    for(UserRecordAccess recAccess : listUserRecordAccess){
        accessMap.put(recAccess.RecordId, recAccess.HasReadAccess);
    }

    for(Pricebook2 R : Records){
        if(accessMap.get(R.Id)){
            Options.add(new SelectOption(R.Id, R.Name));
        }
    }

    return Options;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Just by the amount of upvote this question received in 18 hours (7 at this time!), it's clear that it will help others.

Comment: Thanks.  Did it work for you?  Or did you come up with another workaround?

Comment: Troubleshooting a problem in the `UserRecordAccess` request. I'll update as soon as I find the issue, but I'm on a good track :)!

Comment: Good to hear.  Good luck

Comment: I'm surprised to see that it is not working :S! Pasting code in my initial question

Comment: It seems like the list returned has `yes` everywhere, so I think it's not possible to get information from there...

Comment: If you are a system admin, which I assume you are, it should return true for all.  have you logged in as another profile that has resgtricted voew to certain pricebooks and tested?

Comment: Of course, I have the same result for a user who doesn't have access.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/11515/discussion-between-jpmonette-and-sf-ninja)

Comment: I too tried the workaround as mentioned by @sfdc_ninja but ,I am getting all the records  as said by jpmonette.Any solution found for it?

Comment: @sfdc_ninja  have u found any solution for it?

Comment: Thank you @ChrisDuncombe for this solution! Who knows why SFDC limited 
with sharing to exclude pricebooks but this is a great workaround!